# Opening Chrome browser in full window or kiosk mode on windows 7

Tags: google-chrome

I have tried all the following and I just can't get Chrome to open in fullscreen with or without kiosk mode:

[Run chrome in fullscreen mode on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649264/run-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode-on-windows)

Which says simply to create a shortcut with the following as target:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -kiosk -fullscreen WEBSITE TO OPEN
```

I have tried with -- and -

I have tried creating a BAT file and using the following

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk --fullscreen "WEBSITE TO OPEN"
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Don't you have any other Chrome window open ?  It only works if no other instance of Chrome is running...

Comment: No other chrome windows open.

Answer (score 8):

for anyone here that want to open a new chrome window without url bar it is not called kiosk mode, it is called app mode. and the command to append to your chrome path is:

```
--app=https://google.com
```

Comment: wrong
 --app opens app mode, which has no toolbar but is not maximized.

--kiosk opens fullscreen with no toolbar

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to open the Chrome browser in a full window or kiosk mode on Windows 7:

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe
start chrome.exe --kiosk -tab "www.url.com"
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code a bit more in your answer?

Comment: @RyanKozak after cleaning up the commands, it looks a lot easier :)

Comment: Can confirm that this works in Windows 10 as well.
In case anyone wondering, copy the code into a new text file and change the ending to .bat then add the correct url and you should be good to go. Also; an url that contains % must instead use %% to be interpreted correctly as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026786/open-url-that-contains-umlaut-with-batch).

Answer (score 2):

In order for the target path:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk WEBSITE TO OPEN
```

to work, you need to quit all chrome processes, including background process. You can actually disallow chrome to run in background.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649264/run-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode-on-windows)

But, there is an alternative to using the above approach.

- Add the kiosk app(extension) to your chrome.
- In the kiosk app
  settings, give the URL and other details as appropriate(You can
  launch the app from webstore after adding it to chrome).
- From the `extensions` window of
  chrome, click on details of Kiosk extension and click on `create app shortcuts` button.
- Use the shortcuts created to enter chrome in kiosk
  mode.

Comment: This is the answer that helped me! We're using Chrome to display a webpage as a building directory, so this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the chrome browser is closed down, all instances of Chrome.exe in the Windows Task Manager need to be manually closed. Even if testing when a PC is freshly turned on, I still need to close instances of Chrome.exe from the Windows Task Manager.

When all instances are closed, running a shortcut with the following target seems to work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --chrome --fullscreen --kiosk
```

Does anyone know how to stop the instances of Chrome.exe in the Windows Task manager interfering?

Comment: also, what is the purpose of --chrome parameter?

Answer (score 1):

close the browser and just try this way "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Add new user. Create a name and image for it.
- Step 2: Create desktop shortcut (Check the checkbox that says "Create desktop
  shortcut")
- Step 3: Go to Desktop, right-click the shortcut, left-click "Properties".
- Step 4: Under "Target", at the end of the string, type "--kiosk" (without the quotes)
- Step 5: Click Apply, close ALL OPEN INSTANCES OF CHROME, and start Chrome from that shortcut you created in Step 2.
- The end. I have looked it up myself, and it works 100%.