# Open URL that contains umlaut with batch

Tags: batch-file, url, encoding, automation

I want to open an URL in chrome with a batch file. This works for normal URLs, but it doesn't for URLs with umlauts.

```
start chrome.exe https://trends.google.de/trends/explore?q=mähroboter
```

I cannot use "ae" as a replacement for "ä", as it will give me different results on Google Trends.

When I keep it like this, the URL in my browser changes to

```
https://trends.google.de/trends/explore?q=mA4hroboter
```

which again gives me the wrong results. It needs to be "ä".

I tried playing around with the file encoding. Currently UTF8 without BOM. I tried UTF8 with BOM, ANSI, converting to and fro. Nothing seemed to work. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs must be [URL encoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) with [percent-encoded bytes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encoded-bytes).

That means the German umlaut `ä` in a [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) must be first [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded with the two bytes with the hexadecimal values `C3 A4` and next percent-encoded resulting in `%C3%A4` in the URL string:

```
https://trends.google.de/trends/explore?q=m%C3%A4hroboter
```

In a batch file a percent sign must be escaped with an additional percent sign to get it interpreted by Windows command processor as literal character and not

- as beginning of a batch file argument reference as explained by help of command **CALL** output on running `call /?` in a command prompt window, or
- beginning of a loop variable reference as explained by help of command **FOR** output on running `for /?` in a command prompt window, or
- beginning / end of an environment variable reference as explained by help of command **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window.

So in the batch file must be used:

```
start chrome.exe https://trends.google.de/trends/explore?q=m%%C3%%A4hroboter
```