# How to run R Shiny App in full-sized window?

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to set Shiny options to open an App automatically in a full view mode, i.e. in a maximized window?

My user interface is designed in a way that is nicely looking only when browsed in a full view.

My source is written in two standard files: server.R and ui.R.

I am interested in both options: to run app in (1) RStudio Window and in (2) External browser.

Although this appears to me as a natural and simple question, I cannot find any suggestion when searching the web. Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are asking for is browser dependent and cannot be *enforced* from *R* or *Shiny*. I had this same requirement for a conference where I deployed an app as a team activity, all the conference tables had a connected tablet. Note that the reason why this is difficult comes down to security and the risks of *phishing* / *social engineering*. Some additional information on this:

- [Fullscreen specification](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#security-and-privacy-considerations)
- [Using the HTML5 Fullscreen API for Phishing Attacks - Feross.org](https://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/)

You have a few options depending on the constraints of your circumstances, in no particular order:

1. **Request for the browser to switch to fullscreen mode via *javascript***

There is a [*Fullscreen API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) you could use to *request* the browser to switch to fullscreen mode. The benefit here is that it is browser and platform agnostic provided the browser supports the API. However, it is only a *request* and not guaranteed to work as intended. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228377/could-a-website-force-the-browser-to-go-into-fullscreen-mode) question (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre) one) demonstrates an implementation, you could use the excellent [`shinyjs`](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package if you choose to go down this path.

Here is a minimal example demonstrating the use of the *Fullscreen API.* using an adaptation of the [*Old Faithful Geyser Data*](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/faithful.html) demonstration app.

**app.R**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)
    
    jsToggleFS <- 'shinyjs.toggleFullScreen = function() {
        var element = document.documentElement,
          enterFS = element.requestFullscreen || element.msRequestFullscreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullscreen,
          exitFS = document.exitFullscreen || document.msExitFullscreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || document.webkitExitFullscreen;
        if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
          enterFS.call(element);
        } else {
          exitFS.call(document);
        }
      }'

    ui <- fluidPage(

      useShinyjs(),
      extendShinyjs(text = jsToggleFS),

      titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

      sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
        div(
          HTML("<button type='button'>Toggle Fullscreen</button>"),
          onclick = "shinyjs.toggleFullScreen();"
        )
      ),

      mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")

      ))
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {

      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

> **N.B.** If you are implementing this, you may choose something more advanced than my very simplistic HTML button. It is important to note that browsers will only allow the use of the API if initiated by the user. You may find the message `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.` in your *javascript* console if not detected as a user event.

There is also the [`screenfull.js`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) library, which tries to package up the API in a more friendly way.

2. **Deploy your app using some form of *kiosk* mode**

Browsers can be instructed to start in *kiosk* mode (*i.e.* fullscreen), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649264/run-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode-on-windows) for an example with *Chrome* on windows. The problem here of course is that unless you are working in a standard environment (like an enterprise) this could be highly frustrating to execute.

3. **Use a browser that is specifically designed to use fullscreen mode all the time**

Because my platform was android for the conference, I used an app (not [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.klurige.fullscreenbrowser&hl=en) one but similar) and I placed a shortcut link on the main page after making this browser the default for opening pages. Not ideal, but it met my immediate requirements.

4. **Accept current state / Inform users**

Given there is a level of *fragility* with the available solutions and security concerns regardless of how you choose to tackle this problem, you may opt to accept the current state and layout your app as best you can with this knowledge. Or possibly just inform your users that the app is optimised for use fullscreen and that they can press `F11` (or equivalent) in their browser to enable that.

Comment: Thanks for this - for Javascript option (1) - would you know how to implement that by any chance in an R / Shiny context? I.e. know of a minimal working Shiny example?

Comment: Many thanks for that - typically I guess one would just like to have the Shiny app execute shinyjs.toggleFullScreen() upon initialization, rather than when the user clicks the HTML button (as that would be practically the same as the user clicking the maximize button). Can that be done too?

Comment: @TomWenseleers, no, as noted in my answer it is not allowed for security reasons. You can find many debates discussing this on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: @TomWenseleers, I will add that you could get creative with the user event that triggers the javascript. The most obvious would be to have a landing page that the user needs to navigate to get to your app and have that process launch your app fullscreen.

Comment: Yes or maybe detecting an event that will always happen, like hover with the cursor over some part of the shiny app, and then making sure that that event is only triggered once? Would that be an option?

Comment: @TomWenseleers, yes, any user gesture can be used. However, just be aware it is generally considered bad practice (bordering on unethical/immoral) when your site behaves in a way that the user could not anticipate or expect reasonably.

Comment: This is a great answer about full screen, however I believe there is a difference between maximized window and full screen window, and maximized window doesn't have the problems of phishing / social engineering.

Comment: Anybody can replace `extendShinyjs(text = jsToggleFS)` by `extendShinyjs(text = jsToggleFS, functions = c("toggleFullScreen"))` in to order to avoid error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to running full-screen is to open your app in a different browser from RStudio.

Next to the shiny app launch button there is a tiny triangle that opens a drop-down menu.  Within this menu, just click on the icon to change the displaying option to Run External.  If you change to external, every time you click Run App it will open in your default browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not how to change the browser type (ex. from RStudio Window to External browser), but how to have full size window immediately after launching an App (without clicking 'maximalize' icon).

Comment: If you keep your browser full-screen and relaunch your app, it will remain full-screen (at least in Chrome on Windows). This can be convenient for development. Sadly, it opens a new tab each time you start the browser, but they all are full-screen.

Comment: Letting [the app close itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590324/1048186) when you close the tab is a nice workaround

Comment: Sadly, I don't think it is possible to do the other way. [This snippet](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/close-window/app.R) will close the window, but it doesn't work when executed in onSessionEnded() or onStop()