# How to make a shiny app full screen automatically?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am using `shinymanager` to login a shiny app. Thanks to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371164/how-to-run-r-shiny-app-in-full-sized-window/48086874#48086874) question, I am able to make the page fullscreen by adding an action button on my shiny app. However,  I want the app to be fullscreen automatically  after logging on the app.

I tried to use `observeEvent()` wrt the user authentication as below;

```
auth  <- secure_server( check_credentials = check_credentials(".\\cr\\db.sqlite"))
creds_reactive <- reactive({  auth$user  })

observeEvent(  auth$user, {

        source(".\\funcs\\myfun.R", local = TRUE)  # this works

        js$toggleFullScreen()  # not working

  })
```

I am able to trigger a sourced function by using `auth$user` in `observeEvent()`, but the fullscreen function is not working.

However, I can trigger the very same function at the server side by clicking a button as below.

```
# Server side
     onclick("my_full_screen_button", {
          js$toggleFullScreen()  # this works
    
        })

# Ui side
 tags$li(id="tam",class = "dropdown", 
    actionButton(icon = icon("expand-arrows-alt"), 'my_full_screen_button','',style="color: #fff; background-color: #888888; border-color: #888888") ),
```

I am suspecting that it stems from the `jsToggleFS`. But I have almost no knowledge about JS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

js <- "
function openFullscreen(elem) {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  useShinyjs(),
  ......
```

And in `server`:

```
observeEvent(auth$user, {

  source(".\\funcs\\myfun.R", local = TRUE)  

  runjs("openFullscreen(document.documentElement)")

})
```

Comment: It did not work. By the way, I am using `shinydashboard`. So maybe I couldn't put the ui side at the right place. Any suggestion about that?  (under dashboardBody? or?)

Comment: @maydin Yes, in `dashboardBody`. Also try to put the `runjs` before the `source`.